# Combining all data with a unique ID - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have this data that I got from my current **query**.
[image]

What I want to do is combine and make it a single row where the type is Senior, the cashamount and Tenderamount are the same as  well.

This is my **desired result:**
[image]

I'm getting my data from this **table**:

[image]

Here's my **query:**

```
SELECT a.DATE as `DATE`, a.employee as `EMPLOYEE`,  a.TYPEID, a.NAME as 
`NAME`, (select (case when a.typeid = 1 then a.amount else NULL end)) as 
`CASHAMOUNT`, 
(select (case when a.typeid <> 1 then a.amount else NULL end)) as 
`TENDERAMOUNT`, (select gndtndr.IDENT from gndtndr where gndtndr.TYPE = 12 
and `gndtndr`.`CHECK`= a.CHECK and gndtndr.DATE = a.DATE) as `ID`,  
from gndtndr a
where STR_TO_DATE(a.DATE, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20170901' AND '20170901' 
order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DATE, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `SUMM` for `CASHAMOUNT` and `TENDERAMOUNT`

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Are you trying to group by employee id, or type?

Comment: I just want it to have single column. Like what I said in my desired result.   I wanna group them by ID

Comment: You can not group by `ID`. Better add `SENIOR` into `WHERE` clause and select `SUMM` of `CASHAMOUNT` and `TENDERAMOUNT`

Comment: I cannot sum the amount because the client want to see also the cash that was used.

Comment: See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out :) I just have to define the type conditions in my where clause where the type is 1(for cash).

```
SELECT a.DATE as `DATE`, a.employee as `EMPLOYEE`,  a.TYPEID, a.NAME as 
`NAME`, (select sum(gndtndr.amount) from gndtndr where gndtndr.typeid = 1 
and gndtndr.`CHECK` = a.`CHECK` and gndtndr.DATE = a.DATE) as `CASHAMOUNT`, 
(select (case when a.typeid <> 1 then a.amount else NULL end)) as 
`TENDERAMOUNT`, (select gndtndr.IDENT from gndtndr where gndtndr.TYPE = 12 
and `gndtndr`.`CHECK`= a.CHECK and gndtndr.DATE = a.DATE) as `ID` from 
gndtndr a
where a.TYPEID <> 1 and STR_TO_DATE(a.DATE, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20170901' 
AND '20170901' order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DATE, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL is a bit rusty, but give this a try!

```
SELECT a.Date, a.Employee, a.Name, a.ID, SUM(b.Amount) AS CashAmount, 
SUM(c.Amount) AS TenderAmount FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Date, Employee, Name, ID FROM gndtndr WHERE Type = 12) AS a
LEFT JOIN gndtndr AS b
ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.TypeID = 1
LEFT JOIN gndtdr AS c
ON a.ID = c.ID and c.TypeID <> 1
GROUP BY a.Date, a.Employee, a.Name, a.ID
```